When i trying to execute shell script , it does out come out. keep on running
File name : /u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck1.sql
Shell Script :test.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
line=`sqlplus $SCMDWSA @/u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck.sql`
echo "==    Result of SQL: line = $line"

when I trying to execute shell script 'test.ksh',  step line=sqlplus $SCMDWSA @/u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck.sql  is keep on running, it does not come out.
I want to check, how it works if i changed file name 'appcheck1.sql' instead of 'appcheck.sql' in the path directory.
I want to capture the error, if i keep invalid file in the actual path directory.
could you please help me how to capture the error ?
why it is running long time?

I think the big error is the lack of the closing back-quote.

does sqlplus $SCMDWSA @/u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck.sql executed directly from shell (with variable set) run properly ?

Typically, sqlplus outputs all prompts, warnings, user input, error messages, query results and general commentary to stdout. You are perhaps merely choking ksh with excess text. sqlplus will handle dozens or hundreds of queries in a session: it will not give an error return code for single commands with errors, only for catastrophic failures. Showing the .sql (maybe through PasteBin) would be helpful.

What is PasteBin ?, Could you provide any example

PasteBin refers to the initial example of an internet tool that appeared about 20 years ago, but is now a generic term tool as it has many rivals. It is useful for posting larger texts that you don't want to type into a forum or is difficult to format. The idea is that you can send it your text (data, script etc) and it sends you back a link that you can put in your forum post. Your text is deleted after a while. My Linux came with a command to make it easier, but your distro may differ. Google or Wikipedia may be helpful.
